# Find the vector form of the equation of the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that passes through $P = (2, -1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the vector form of the equation of the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that passes through  $P = (2, - 1 )$ and is parallel to the line with general equation $2x - 3y = 1$.

Following the format of $x = p + td$, I worked through this problem and got the answer;

$$[x, y] = [2, -1] + t[2, -3]$$

I checked the solution guide to confirm my answer and noticed I had the incorrect direction vector, the correct answer is:

$$[x, y] = [2, -1] + t[3, 2]$$

Could anyone help me to understand how they got a direction vector?

Comment: The line $2x-3y=1$ has slope $\frac{2}{3}$. That means for every $3$ units of change in the $x$ direction there are $2$ units of change in the $y$ direction. Thus, $3\hat i + 2\hat j$ is the direction vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direction vector is orthogonal to the normal vector, which is $(2,-3)$. Hence you take $\vec v=(3,2)$, or any vector collinear with $\vec v$.